# Wordpress Themify, how does it auto generate style sheet

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using Wordpress (basic theme) and in my `<head/>` markup there is an auto generated style sheet 
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='themify_cache_header-css'  href='https://myblog.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/themify/cache/basic/styles/home/header-123456789.css?ver=1.2.3' type='text/css' media='all' />`

the path to this file is: `files/themify/cache/basic/styles/home/header-123456789.css`

From header.php inside my theme, this executes the process.

```
/** Themify Default Variables
 *  @var object */
global $themify;
```

I dont know how to control the content of this style sheet and cant seem to find any documentation on how this works.
Does anyone have any experience with this? 
How can I change the content of this css file?

**update** Figured it out, the css file is generated from data  in the dB.  Themes will auto generate style, admin must edit from wp-admin page for WP to write to dB.

Comment: So what is the question, then?

Comment: @cale_b I answered it in the update.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. Self-answers are encouraged here!